# Technical term for services like Sandstorm.io

Tags: saas, paas, sandstorm.io

This isn't exactly a programming question but I thought this would still be the best community to find an answer for my question.
I'd like to know if there is a specific technical term that describes services like [sandstorm.io](http://sandstorm.io). I'm looking for kind of a buzzword more specific than "personal cloud" or "SaaS", describing exactly this model of having packaged web applications available in an app-store for one-click deployment to a private cloud environment.
The reason why I'm looking for such a search word is that I need to do some scientifical research on evaluating such a concept for enterprise application. So if you know some related work for that topic by chance please let me know.
And are there any alternatives with the same concept as Sandstorm?

Answer (score 7):

I'm the founder of Sandstorm and I don't know if there is a precise term to use here. Other "self-hostable personal cloud" platforms include ownCloud, Cozy Cloud, and YunoHost. Other "private cloud app markets" include Bitnami and AppDirect (who actually powers many markets). Other "container engines/infrastructure" include Docker, Rocket, Kubernetes, and Mesos. Other "web application firewalls" include Imperva, f5, Guardium.

Note that Sandstorm's fine-grained containerization model is not implemented by any other platform to my knowledge, and this makes Sandstorm pretty fundamentally different from all these other products.

PS. I'd love to hear the results of your research when they're ready. :)